# Qt - reduce duplication between two QAbstractListModel subclasses

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, multiple-inheritance

I've written two QAbstractListModel subclasses:

```
class Model1: public QAbstractListModel {

Q_OBJECT

public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const;
    void clear();
private:
    QVector<Obj1*> m_items;

};
```

and

```
class Model2: public QAbstractListModel {

Q_OBJECT

public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const;
    void clear();
private:
    QVector<Obj2*> m_items;
};
```

In addition, these two classes have a slot AddObj() which is dependent on the pointer used (`Obj1*` or `Obj2*`).

The matter is, constructors and destructors are the same, and so are `rowCount` and `clear` (they do the *exact* same thing). The only differences are in `data` and in what `m_items` is.

What's the best strategy to reduce duplication here? I tried with a base class:

```
class ModelBase: public QAbstractListModel {

Q_OBJECT

ModelBase(QObject* parent=0);
~ModelBase();

public:
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const = 0;
    virtual void clear();
private:
    QVector<QString*> m_items; // dummy vector

};
```

and then have the other classes derive from it:

```
class ModelDerived1: public ModelBase {

Q_OBJECT
public:
    ModelDerived1(QObject* parent=0);
    ~ModelDerived1();

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const = 0;
private:
    QVector<Obj1*> m_items;

};
```

The problem is that in such a case the derived class's `data` function is never called when this model is attached to a view.

Nevertheless, the derived class `data()` is not called (I put in debug statements, and they are never executed).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `= 0` in your derived model class means that `data` is pure virtual and doesn't have implementation. How can you tell that this function is never called if it doesn't have implementation?

Comment: Not making the method pure virtual doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: How can it not change anything? Creating an implementation of pure virtual method causes compilation errors. If you didn't see errors while compiling original code, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: `data()` in the subclasses is only called if I subclass directly from `QAbstractListModel`, not by any other subclass (I tried with a dummy `data()` function that would only return `QVariant()` in the superclass instead of a pure virtual method).

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The solution is not what I posted here. In fact, it was completely off. The issue is in the `rowCount` function and in the private `m_items` `QVector`.

`rowCount`, if not present, calls the superclass method, which does **not** use the private `m_items` element from the derived class, but it uses the one from the superclass, which being dummy, returns always a size of 0, and thus `data` never gets called.